# Passing optional arguments in Powershell script

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I'm trying to write a code that would check **if arguments exist** and take action accordingly. The code would need to be flexible to run **with or without** arguments when the script is called.

For example:

```
if (arg[0] -And arg[1])
{
    $argOne = arg[0]
    $argTwo = arg[1]
}
else
{
    $argOne = "One"
    $argTwo = "Two"
}
```

This code is obviously **wrong** because I'm not sure how to check if arguments exist in Powershell. In python, there is the functionality of `sys.argv` that stores all arguments into an array. I could then do a try-except to check if the arguments exist. Can I do something similar in Powershell? 
I did some research and `param` was advised to use to handle arguments but I don't think `param` could handle no arguments being passed to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong about `param`!
Came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408440/arguments-with-powershell-scripts-on-launch) which was very helpful.

```
param($one, $two)

if ($one -And $two)
{
    $argOne = $one
    $argTwo = $two
}
else
{
    $argOne = "One"
    $argTwo = "Two"
}
```